# EXCEL VBAでMicrosoft Word XX.X OBject Libraryが参照できない

Tags: vba, excel

EXCEL VBAでMicrosoft Word XX.X OBject Libraryを呼び出して、Wordで文書を作成するマクロを作成しました。これをVBA_1とします。
これは、問題なく動作していました。
ある日、別のVBAで同じようなWord Libraryを呼び出して文書を作成するVBAを作成しました。これをVBA_2とします。これを起動したところ、コーディングにミスがあったらしく、無限ループ状態となりVBAから抜けられなくなりました。
仕方ないのて強制終了しましたが、それ以降、正常に動作していたVBA_1を起動すると、

実行時エラー'-2147319779(8002801d)':
オートメーション エラーです。
ライブラリは登録されていません。

というエラーが出てWordのライブラリを呼び出しできなくなってしまいました。
当然、元々正常に動作していたものなので、参照設定は正しく設定されています。
Officeの修復も実施してみましたが、治りません。
対処方法をご存じの方がいらっしゃいましたら、ご教示いただきたく質問した次第です。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: その `XX.X` として書かれている実際の正確な版数と、実体のDLL/EXEの版数が違っているのかもしれませんね。レジストリに今はもう無い古い版数のDLL/EXEの情報が残っているとか、その情報の指し示す先のDLL/EXEが新しい版数に入れ替わってしまったのかもしれません。こんな記事が参考になるかも。[8002801d automation error - library not registered](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/8002801d-automation-error-library-not-registered/5717123b-4c0b-4a3d-8bb5-7d0fe84e6ac9) あるいは、レジストリを操作する前にこちらの記事 [エクセルVBAでWord(ワード)操作に必要な参照設定とエラー対処方法](https://fastclassinfo.com/entry/vba_set_word/) の`方法2. 参照設定を使わない方法` を試してみるのが良いかもしれません。

Comment: [teratail](https://teratail.com/questions/brlces7sdiwx8o) や [Qiita](https://qiita.com/momotsubo/questions/d76d3f0519f6465a8118) でも同じ内容の投稿をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: [マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418)

Comment: @kunifさま ありがとうございました。 https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/8002801d-automation-error-library-not-registered/5717123b-4c0b-4a3d-8bb5-7d0fe84e6ac9に記載されている「遅延バインディング」によりエラーを回避できました。 但し、これはエラー回避方法であって、解決方法ではない気がします。 引き続き解決方法を模索しています。取り急ぎ御礼まで。